# Prove Limit does not exist: $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find the following:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin(x)$$ I know that this does not exist due to the oscillatory nature of $\sin(x)$,

but I need to prove this using basic limit theorems. Is there a way to apply squeeze theorem to this? Otherwise, what should I do.

Comment: It is *not* because $\sin$ oscillates. It's because $-1 \le \sin(x)\le 1$ for all x, whereas $x\mapsto x$ is unbounded. Consider: $\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(x) = 0$.

Comment: @BrianO: That's not the whole story. It is certainly possible to have $-1 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$, and $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x)$ exists. (Take $f(x) = 0$ for a trivial example, or $f(x) = 1/(1+x^2)$ for a less trivial one.) The issue here is that $\sin(x)$ does not converge to zero as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @Bungo That's all true. I wasn't claiming it's the whole story — that would be an answer. I just wanted OP to think about other features of the problem, as "$\sin$ is periodic" doesn't ensure anything about $f(x)\sin(x)$ in the limit.

Comment: @BrianO yes it does, provided $f(x) \neq 0$ somewhere, which your first comment does not preclude...

Comment: I'm not sure if we are taking $\infty$ to count as a limit. If so then we need periodic + a negative point and a positive point.

Comment: @djechlin and even if $\pm\infty$ count as limits, the function doesn't converge to either, though subsequences do converge to each.

Comment: @BrianO periodic + there is at least one positive point and one negative point is enough to prove exactly that. Just saying "because sin oscillates" plus basically trivial other hypotheses give you every result on this topic, with no other properties of sin being needed, and the bounds of -1 and 1 being irrelevant (except for the "trivial hypothesis" that it reaches a negative point and a positive point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$, then for any sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow \infty$, we also have $f(x_n) \rightarrow L$.

Now consider the sequence $x_n = 2n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}$ for your $f(x) = x\sin(x)$. Also consider $x_n = 2n\pi$, which has an entirely different limit.

Comment: But that only proves the convergence of $f(x)$ won't I need a second sequence that diverges to $-\infty$?

Comment: It depends whether tending to infinity counts as divergence already. If not, take a subsequence to 0 or $-\infty$

Comment: A more ambitious answer (one should always try to improve on an elementary problem if possible):  *Show that for any choice of $-\infty\leq r \leq \infty$ there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\to \infty$ so that $f(x_n)\to r$.*